# multiple name change in folder bash

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

Hi I am using this code :

```
rename 's/\.ubz/.uz/g' *.ubz -vn
```

to change all the files with .ubz to .uz but I also have files with .set so I want to change them to .uz as well. This is what I have tried but it only works for .ubz files and nothing changes on .set

```
rename 's/\.ubz/.uz/g' -a 's/\.set/.uz/g' *.ubz -a *.set -vn
```

Where am I making the mistake? 
Thanks.

Comment: Try: `rename 's/\.(ubz|set)/.uz/g' *.ubz -vn`

Comment: Right, I forgot to add them to the file list. See my answer

Comment: `rename -vn 's/...$/uz/g' *.ubz *.set`

Comment: is there also a way to add a letter to one of the extension?  hugz.ubz to change hugz_ima.ubz and .set to change .ubz without changing anything. I am able to do it with 2 lines thanks to your answers but I was just wondering if it could be done with just one line

Comment: Use `'s/regex1/string1/;s/regex2/string2/'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
rename 's/\.(ubz|set)/.uz/g' *.ubz *.set -vn
```